# exclude url from htaccess redirect 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I got shop that redirect all request from http to https.
I need to exclude one url from this rule.
I search through other threads on stack, but none of the solution works for me.

I'm testing in on http://htaccess.mwl.be and I still got "*This condition is not met*" result for my new condition. I don't know there I made mistake

url is:

> mypage.domain/index.php?route=payment/payu/ordernotify

My htaccess (redirect part only)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^route=payment\/payu\/ordernotify$ [NC] #my not working exclude condition

RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would not it be easier to use a simple string?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=route=payment/payu/ordernotify
```

Comment: One step closer.
Now validator shows that condition was met, but request is still redirect.

Comment: I made a mistake. The quotes were unnecessary.

Comment: Confirm, working.
Today is work free day (national celebration) in Poland. Thanks to you I will not have to spend it to solve this kind of irritating problems. Thanks a lot.